# How to Post on Google+ community using Google Apps Script or Java

Tags: java, post, google-apps-script, google-plus

How to Post on Google+ community using Google Apps Script or Java.

I am able to post on Google+ Circle only using Java as well as in Google Apps Script. I tried to find it out on Google but no solution is there.

Answer (score 0):

You cant write to communities with the Google+ API.  A number of issue requests have been created for this on the [Google-plus-Platform issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list)

Comment: Yes you are right. We can't post on Google+ Community. I too didn't find anything. But google Should include it.

Comment: You cant post anywhere in Google+ using the API its one of the major drawbacks to the API

Comment: We can post on our circles of Google+ for e.g. Friends or Family using Google+ API.

Comment: No you can post to a Google+ wall through the api